# Can't connect to replicaset in Compass

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, replicaset

I'm trying to connect to my local mongodb replicaset using Compass but it's raising `connection 0 to localhost:27017 closed`.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
mongo:
    image: library/mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--port", "27017", "--bind_ip", "localhost", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
```

After starting the container, I'm running:

```
rs.initiate()
```

All of this using this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Here is the connection string I'm trying to use:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/test?replicaSet=rs0
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What happens if you try to connect to the replica-set from the terminal, using this connection string?

Answer (score 2):

to do so: first go to your mongo path. On windows, the path is like this:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
```

Here you can find mongo.exe cmd, run it and type

```
db.adminCommand( { shutdown : 1} )
```

which will shutdown your instance.

Next go to mongo path on your system in cmd with administrator privilege:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
```

According to [Official mongo document about Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

enter following command:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data" --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
```

which --dbpath is your databases path and --replSet your replication name. Now come back to mongo shell and type

```
 rs.initiate()
```

and connect via compass by specifying  "Replica Set Name"

[image: Replica Set Name in mongodb]

and everything gonna be alright.

*** By the way, keep in mind that replication must be alive during your development and keep it running.